# How to limit access of eventhub to specific consumergroup

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I've an eventhub and I want to share the access rights specific for a consumer group.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That is currently (Oct-2019) not possible. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-authentication-and-security-model-overview#authentication-of-back-end-applications

> The current version of Service Bus **does not support SAS rules** for individual subscriptions. The same holds true **for Event Hubs consumer groups**. SAS support will be added for both features in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any kind of workaround for this use case?

Comment: Hm, either have a seperate event hub per subscriber (in the same namespace) or build your own API around it?! Neither are ideal options, I know

Comment: I'm evaluating the idea of having a specific eventhub for each application but I think it will be very expensive

Comment: what is the risk that you want to mitigate by having different access policies on each consumer group? the data is the same in all of them anyway. The only thing people could do, is mess with each others watermarks. You could try to mitigate that a little bit by assigning very long and cryptic names to the consumer groups (security by obscurity...)

Comment: obscurity will be an option of course, the problem is on the producing side. I would avoid for a producer to write on multiple topics.

Comment: then you do have a misunderstanding there. All messages will go into all consumer groups. The producer is not aware of those and cannot limit his messages to certain consumer groups

Comment: if I write on a consumergroup and I read from a consumergroup I'm not reading only those data?

Comment: you cannot write to a specific consumer group! all messages that you write into an event hub will be available on all groups!

Comment: ok, there is a method to send/read on a specific partion otherwise? I mean if I can send on a specific partition and read from a consumer group associated with a specifi partition maybe it could be a solution

Comment: I read about the properties, If I can send an eventData with a particular properties I can filter on it when I read